# Cannot set enum type in published property of a component

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am writing a component and this is the main class with the most important pieces of code:

```
uses
  Equation;

type
 TEquationSolver = class(TComponent)
   private
     FSolver: TSolverType;
   published
     property RootFindAlgorithm: TSolverType read FSolver write FSolver;
 end;
```

In the uses clauses I've added `Equation` because inside `Equation.pas` I have declared this kind of enum:

```
type
 TSolverType = (TNewtonRaphson = 0, TSecant, TBisection, TBrent);
```

In this way I am able to have in the IDE an option in the Object Inspector with a dropdown menu.

---

I have installed the component and while I was testing I've found this problem:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   EquationSolver1.RootFindAlgorithm := TSolverType.Secant;
end;
```

The error is the following:

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(29): E2003 Undeclared identifier:
>   'TSolverType'

My question is very simple: why?

In the Unit where I am running the test (simple VCL form) there is the component with its uses included and so I am able to "see" `TEquationSolver`. As you can see at the top inside the unit of TEquationSolver I have included `Equation` and the latter has TSolverType.

The situation is the following:

[image]

Do I have to add something under the `uses` somewhere? I don't want to add stuff to the `uses` of Unit1.

Comment: Why would you make this a component? Why not derive from TObject?

Comment: You describe the relationship as an "include" relationship, but that's not true. It's a "uses" relationship, and unit usage is not transitive in the way inclusion is.

Comment: OT: I'd remove the `= 0` after `TNewtonRaphson`. It doesn't gain you anything (the ordinal values stay the same) but removes RTTI and maybe more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make `TSolverType` visible to a unit (eg a Form), you must tell that unit where `TSolverType` is defined. That is part of how Delphi works.

Therefore, you have to either:

- include `Equation` in the `uses` clause of the unit where you want to us the definition (eg the Form's unit)
- include `TSolverType` in your component's unit
- hide the property (eg by making it `private` or `protected`).

Delphi does not support implied definitions in the way you hope.

Comment: Ok thank you, I guess I'll add TSolverType to the component unit.

Comment: There is another option, at least at design-time. Create a design-time package for the component, and have that package define a `TSelectionEditor`-derived class that overrides `RequiresUnits()`, and then register the class with `RegisterSelectionEditor()`. `RequiresUnits()` can report that `'Equation'` is a required unit. That way, when a user drops a `TEquationSolver` on a Form at design-time, `Equation` is automatically added to the Form's `uses` clause. This won't solve the issue if a user creates a `TEquationSolver` in code at runtime, though. They would have to add `Equation` manually.